# Infopath - Parent / Child Forms for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I need to implement a solution for a client SharePoint Office 365 site.  I know you can do things with 3 parts solutions or Jquery but I'm trying to keep it OOTB as possible.  Here is a simplistic view of the scenario.

There is a list called Parent.  It has one field `Title`.
There is a second list called Child.  It has one field `Title` and another `Parent`
`Parent` is the type Lookup and points to the `Title` field of the Parent list.

The SharePoint form is for the Parent List so the main connection points there.

I simply want to create a data connection to the child list and have the Edit / View pages populate that a listbox with the ID(Value) and Title(Display) from the corresponding match in the Parent list.

I've tried several ways but I lack the experience to probably describe what I've tried (Using Rules and the `lists.asmx` as well as a retrieve data connection to child and filtering it upon load).

Thank you in advance, I really need to get this implemented.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, I understand you want to open the form on the click of the list item with the view & edit.
for that you have to create the rules with the proper actions like if I click on the parent A then form open but after the form open we have to fetch the ID & title again by the create the connection who dynamically operate as per the call of action.if you need more details please mention comment on this / If I understand wrong the please brief your problem with the example.

Thanks